# Test Automapper Configurations with dynamic types

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, automapper

I'm building out a test package to ensure that all instances where we are calling an automapper mapping have been defined within the Automapper profile, however I'm struggling to pass through types dynamically to the tests

```
[TestCase(typeof(Team), typeof(TeamDTO))]
[TestCase(typeof(TeamManager), typeof(TeamManagerDTO))]
public void AutoMapperTests(Type toType, Type fromType)
{
    var fromObject = Activator.CreateInstance(fromType);
    var toObject = mapper.Map<toType>(fromObject);

    Assert.That(toType, Is.EqualTo(toObject.GetType()));
    Assert.NotNull(toObject);
}
```

I have tried both toType.GetType() as well as trying to pass the typeof, but is there a way to pass the class (Team or TeamManager) into the method so that the mapper knows what it is trying to map to?

Comment: You can use a non generic `Map` overload.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Lucian in the comment, moving to the generic map function helps you be able to test with types passed in to the method.

I struggled with reflecting the actual Types passed in but creating instances of those types allowed for the mapper to be called and get everything running

```
[TestCase(typeof(Team), typeof(TeamDTO))]
[TestCase(typeof(TeamManager), typeof(TeamManagerDTO))]
public void CommandHandlers_Mappings_AreDefined(Type toType, Type fromType)
{
    var fromObject = Activator.CreateInstance(fromType);
    var toObject = Activator.CreateInstance(toType);
    var toObjectMapped = mapper.Map(fromObject, fromObject.GetType(), toObject.GetType());

    Assert.NotNull(toObjectMapped);
    Assert.That(toType, Is.EqualTo(toObjectMapped.GetType()));
}
```

Comment: Try `Map(source, destination)` instead. You should get the same result.